# Returning pointer to an array of struct with single or double pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The objective of my code is as follows:

1. Return a pointer to the array of `innerStruct` either through single or double pointer (I believe I should use double pointer)
2. Pass that pointer to a function that modifies the value

It seems that I get a seg fault in the online compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int innerVal;

} innerStruct;

typedef struct
{
    int           a;
    innerStruct * inner[3];

} myStruct;

static myStruct * m1;

innerStruct ** getInnerPtrToArray()
{
    return &(m1->inner);
}

void processInnerStruct(innerStruct * array_ptr[])
{
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        array_ptr[i]->innerVal = i;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    innerStruct ** array_ptr = getInnerPtrToArray();
    processInnerStruct(array_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Online compiler: https://onlinegdb.com/r1z0DPICb

Comment: You've never allocated any memory for the pointers in the `inner` array.

Comment: `innerStruct` is never initialized anywhere.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @chux Presumably how to fix the the segfault he's getting.

Comment: @Barmar A reasonable assumption, yet such question-less questions tends to lack focus as they can (de-) evolve into  a general back and forth.  By posting a crisp question - the improved post can be objectively answered.

Comment: You also never assigned `m1` to point to concrete memory either. So the dereference in `getInnerPtrToArray` invokes *undefined behavior* from the start.

Comment: @chux I think you're being too pedantic. When a question describes an error, it's obviously asking how to fix that error. Does someone really have to add "How can I fix that?" just so there's something in the actual form of a question?

Comment: @Barmar Does someone really have to add "How can I fix that?" -> No.  Yet it does improve the question - often because the OP then does narrow and clarify the issue and helps prevents ongoing [additional questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044652/returning-pointer-to-an-array-of-struct-with-single-or-double-pointer?noredirect=1#comment81037151_47044753).

Answer (score 1):

Since `inner` is an array of pointers, you need to allocate memory for them to point to. You also need to allocate memory for `m1` to point to.

```
int main() 
{
    m1 = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        m1->inner[i] = malloc(sizeof(innerStruct));
    }
    innerStruct ** array_ptr = getInnerPtrToArray();
    processInnerStruct(array_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Regarding the code `getInnerPtrToArray` and `processInnerStruct`, is that the right way to handle the array of pointers to structs?

Comment: Yes, those functions are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a second cut on what you were doing. Rather than allocating, you can also change `myStruct` to simply contain an array of `innerStruct` rather than an *array of pointers to `innerStruct`*. Then no allocation is needed, e.g.

```
#define NINNER 3    /* if you need a constant, define one */
...
typedef struct {
    int           a;
    innerStruct inner[NINNER];   /* you are not allocating */
} myStruct;
```

**note:** avoid the use of globals, they are not needed. Declare your variables in `main()` and pass as parameters as required.

Putting it altogether, adjusting types as required, and including further notes as comments in-line below, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NINNER 3    /* if you need a constant, define one */

typedef struct {
    int innerVal;
} innerStruct;

typedef struct {
    int a;
    innerStruct inner[NINNER];   /* you are not allocating */
} myStruct;

/* takes pointer to m1, returns address of array of 3 innerStruct */
innerStruct *getInnerPtrToArray (myStruct *innerptr)
{
    return innerptr->inner;
}

/* takes pointer to array of innerStruct, fills */
void processInnerStruct (innerStruct *array_ptr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NINNER; i++)
        array_ptr[i].innerVal = i;
}

int main (void) {

    myStruct m1 = { .a = 10 };  /* don't use globals */
    /* pass the address of m1 */
    innerStruct *array_ptr = getInnerPtrToArray (&m1);
    processInnerStruct (array_ptr);

    printf ("m1.a: %d\n", m1.a);        /* output values */
    for (int i = 0; i < NINNER; i++)
        printf ("  .inner[%d]: %d\n", i, m1.inner[i].innerVal);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/inner
m1.a: 10
  .inner[0]: 0
  .inner[1]: 1
  .inner[2]: 2
```

It's up to you to determine whether you intended to allocate for each of the `3` `innerStruct` in `myStruct`, but from my reading of what you were attempting to do, and with no `stdlib.h` included, it appeared your intent was to handle the array without allocation. Let me know if you have further questions.